# orderByChild not working even though I'm using forEach

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I recently implemented `createdOnNeg` on the data I have for `uploads` document, I'm trying to get the data through `createdOnNeg` instead of `createdBy` so that I could get a sorted data. Here's my firebase function that gets it which also uses pagination (pagination might not be implemented correctly but this is literally the only way I found to make it work and it's surprisingly working):

```
exports.getUserContent = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const userId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

    const limit = 10;
    const page = req.body.page || 1;

    let lastKnownKeyValue = null;
    const userdata = {};

    const uploadsRef = admin.database().ref('uploads').orderByChild("createdOnNeg"); // changing createdOnNeg to createdBy is returning the expected uploads data, which was originally like this

    const allQuery = uploadsRef.equalTo(userId);
    const pageQuery = uploadsRef.equalTo(userId).limitToFirst((limit * page) - limit + 1);

    allQuery.once("value", snapshot => {
        const grandTotalNumberOfQueries = snapshot.numChildren()

        pageQuery.once('value', snapshot => {
            const totalNumberOfQueries = snapshot.numChildren();
            const isEndOfQuery = grandTotalNumberOfQueries - (totalNumberOfQueries - 1) < limit;

            let nextQuery;

            if (page === 1){
                nextQuery = uploadsRef.equalTo(userId).limitToFirst(limit * page);
            } else if (isEndOfQuery && page !== 1){
                const lastQuery = grandTotalNumberOfQueries - (totalNumberOfQueries - 1);
                nextQuery = uploadsRef.equalTo(userId).limitToLast(lastQuery);
            } else {
                snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
                    lastKnownKeyValue = childSnapshot.key
                });
                nextQuery = uploadsRef.startAt(userId, lastKnownKeyValue).limitToFirst(limit);
            }

            nextQuery.once("value", nextSnapshot => {
                userdata.content = {};

                nextSnapshot.forEach(child => {
                    let content = {};
                    content.id = child.key;
                    content.val = child.val();

                    userdata.content[child.key] = content;
                });

                res.json({
                    status: "ok",
                    userdata,
                    totalNumberOfUploads: grandTotalNumberOfQueries
                })
            })
        });

    })
});
```

Here's how the data inside the database looks:
[image]

Please note that this code works when I use `createdBy` instead of `createdOnNeg`. When I log the snapshots (`snapshot.val()`), `createdBy` is showing the expected output while `createdOnNeg` isn't; It's just returning null.

And also note that I'm getting the `username` and `idToken` from the front-end to get the `userId` and use it to fetch data, this code is reduced to remove the unnecessary data.

**EDIT:**
For the sake of simplification, here's a reduced code that also doesn't work:

```
exports.getUserContent2 = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const userId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

    admin.database().ref('uploads').orderByChild("createdOnNeg").equalTo(userId).on('value', snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
            console.log(childSnapshot.val())
        })

        res.json({
            status: 'done'
        })
    })
});
```

And these are the rules I've set:

```
"uploads":{
    "$id":{
        ".write":"newData.child('createdBy').val() == auth.uid",
        ".read":false
    },
    ".indexOn":"createdOnNeg"
}
```

In the above above, when I change `createdOnNeg` to `createdBy` and change the uploads rules index to `".indexOn":"createdBy"`, it works as expected and `console.log(childSnapshot.val())` logs all the results, however, `createdOnNeg` does not return anything, not even `null`.

**Edit 2:**
Following Frank's suggestion, I changed the code to the following and it still didn't work as expected. This time the data was being returned in ascending order but returning null when I tried descending through `startAt()` and `endAt()` functions.

```
exports.getUserContentTest = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const userId = '222';

    const createdOnNegStartAt = '-999999999999999';
    const createdOnNegEndAt = '-1';
    // It would work when I switch the data of createdOnNegStartAt and createdOnNegEndAt but wouldn't return in descending order, as expected.

    const startAt = `${userId}_${createdOnNegStartAt}`;
    const endAt = `${userId}_${createdOnNegEndAt}`;

    admin.database().ref('testuser').orderByChild("createdBy_createdOnNeg").startAt(startAt).endAt(endAt).on('value', snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
            console.log(childSnapshot.val())
        })

        res.json({
            status: 'done'
        })
    })
});
```

[image]

`console.log()` result when I switch the numbers in `createdOnNegStartAt` and `createdOnNegEndAt`:

```
>  {
>    createdBy: 222,
>    createdBy_createdOnNeg: '222_-11111111111',
>    username: 'cedric'
>  }
>  {
>    createdBy: 222,
>    createdBy_createdOnNeg: '222_-22222222222',
>    username: 'something'
>  }
>  {
>    createdBy: 222,
>    createdBy_createdOnNeg: '222_-33333333333',
>    username: 'widjxwafj'
>  }
```

Expected log:

```
>  {
>    createdBy: 222,
>    createdBy_createdOnNeg: '222_-33333333333',
>    username: 'widjxwafj'
>  }
>  {
>    createdBy: 222,
>    createdBy_createdOnNeg: '222_-22222222222',
>    username: 'something'
>  }
>  {
>    createdBy: 222,
>    createdBy_createdOnNeg: '222_-11111111111',
>    username: 'cedric'
>  }
```

Comment: You've shared quite a lot of code there, and I'm having a hard time understanding what isn't working. When you step through this code in a debugger, which specific line isn't doing what you expect it to do? Or alternatively: can you put a `console.log()` statement in the code that highlights the problem, and show us the updated code and its (problematic) output?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I tried logging all snapshots using `console.log(snapshot.val())` and all of them returned null with `createdOnNeg` while they didn't (they returned the data correctly) when I used `createdBy`.

Comment: Instead of describing what you did in comments, please edit your question to show the code that gives you the unexpected output - and the output it gives.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hey Frank, I further included more simplified code, would you have a look at it please?

Comment: This seems unlikely to ever work: `orderByChild("createdOnNeg").equalTo(userId)`, since you're ordering on `createdOnNeg` that is also what you're filtering on - and it seems unlikely that `userId` will ever be a value of `createdOnNeg`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I just noticed that, thank you for pointing that out. Is there any way I can put multiple conditions? That is, `createdBy` should equal to the given `userId` and sort it using `createdOnNeg`?

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. So for example you could create, and then order/filter on `"createdBy_createdOnNeg": "uidOfUser_negativeScore"`. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hey Frank, thanks for your input. Would appreciate it if you could have a look at the 2nd edit I made on the post.

Comment: Instead of specifying specific values for the score, I think you're looking for `startAt(userId).endAt(userId+"~")`. The `~` in there is just an ASCII character that is after all digits, so it's guaranteed that all scores for the user are before that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It was still returning `222_-11111111111` -> `222_-22222222222` -> ... instead of `222_-33333333333` -> `222_-2222222222`, so I removed the negative sign and it worked as expected. (`222_1111111111` first, then `222_22222222222`, etc)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hey Frank, is there any way I can get the data in reverse? i.e `222_33333333333` and then `222_22222222222` and then `222_11111111111`? I got confused last time and my solution wasn't correct. Putting negative value in the database to `222_-1111111111` isn't changing anything. Your help would be appreciated.